# How to add translations to $translateProvider from outside the config?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services, angular-translate, angular-transitions

I am new to angular js. For language translation I am using angular-translate service in my work.I am getting the entire translations which I need to assign in $translateProvider by an API call response.I know that I can assign the translations to $translateprovider ($translateprovider.translations ('en',translations) only from config module but I think that an API call from config module is not a good practise.

Below given is my config module.

```
    .config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {

            //fetching session key
            var response;
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'https://abcdefg/session?appKey=123456',
                async: false,
               success: function(data) {
                   response = data;
                    getMetaData(response.sessionKey);

                }
            });

            ////fetching data.
            function getMetaData(sessionKey) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: 'https://abcdefg/metadata?sessionKey=' + sessionKey +
                        '&gid=1.2.3.4',
                    async: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        dataSet = data; //save response in rootscope variable
                    }
                });
            }


            $translateProvider.translations('en_US', JSON.parse(dataSet.en_us));
            $translateProvider.translations('es_ES', JSON.parse(dataSet.es_es));
            $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');
}
```

How can this be solved? How can I assign translations to $translateProvider from out side the config module?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not call the `app.config( yourNewTranslateProviderConfig)` whereever you want?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry I did't get what do you mean by the 'yourNewTranslateProviderConfig'?

Comment: do you mean get the proffered language from API get ?
 $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');

Comment: or You want to get the translation array from api?

Comment: I want t to get translation array from api.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this @Anna

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [answer from the creator of angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Asynchronous-loading), where he states that "[...]there's no way to extend existing translations during runtime with $translate service without using asynchronous loading.[...]"

For more information on asynchronous loading of translations take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/wiki/Asynchronous-loading). You may even specify your own custom loader to get translations by calling your API.

Answer (score 0):

By many purposes, we may need to add more translations in Services, so I found a way to do that.
We can create another CustomProvider which returns $translateProvider, and then we can inject CustomProvider to Services or Controllers.

```
// NOTE: Create another Provider returns $translateProvider
.provider('CustomProvider', function($translateProvider) {
  this.$get = function() {
    return $translateProvider;
  };
});

// NOTE: Inject CustomProvider to Service to use
.factory('TranslationService', function(CustomProvider) {

  console.log(CustomProvider);

  return {
    addMoreTranslations: addMoreTranslations
  };

  function addMoreTranslations(key, translations) {
    // Do somethings
    CustomProvider.translations(key, translations);
  }
});
```

I succeeded by that way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Xuan Tai Nguyen response, how it worked for me was to include the custom provider between [] in the factory:

```
.factory('TranslationService', ['CustomProvider'], function(CustomProvider) {
```

Hope this helps someone

I'm using angular-translate 2.13.1 with angular 1.4.3